# Using ASP.net to pass parameters to external website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am trying to access a page where I need to log into the website and pass a a list of parameters.  I appear to be able to log into the site (if I change the log in details I get a 401 unauthorised error) but then I get a 400 bad request error.  The code is a bit hashed together so I know something is wrong but don't know where.

EDITED CODE

```
        Public Sub TestConn()


    Dim customeremailaddress As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("r.test@test.com")
    Dim customername As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Ryan")
    Dim referenceid As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ordertest123")
    Dim languagecode As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1043")
    Dim expirydays As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("30")

    Dim UserName As String = "testusername"
    Dim password As String = "testpassword"
    Dim siteCredentials As New NetworkCredential(UserName, password)

    Dim URLAuth As String = "http://service.someurl.com/process.xml"
    Dim postString As String = String.Format("customeremailaddress={0}&customername={1}&referenceid={2}&languagecode={3}&expirydays={4}", customeremailaddress, customername, referenceid, languagecode, expirydays)

    Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString)

    Const contentType As String = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

    Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
    Dim webRequest__1 As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(URLAuth), HttpWebRequest)
    webRequest__1.Method = "POST"
    webRequest__1.ContentType = contentType
    webRequest__1.CookieContainer = cookies
    webRequest__1.ContentLength = postBytes.Length
    webRequest__1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
    webRequest__1.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
    webRequest__1.Referer = "http://service.someurl.com/process.xml"
    webRequest__1.Credentials = siteCredentials

    Try
        Dim requestStream As Stream = webRequest__1.GetRequestStream()
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
        Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(webRequest__1.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
        responseReader.Close()
        webRequest__1.GetResponse().Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Lbl_ConnTest_error.Text = ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Id start by using Fiddler2 http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to have a look at the request/response details and see if that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Also check out this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/debx8sh9.aspx - it might be easier to read - also as its POSTing data dont forget to properly format the postData i.e. url encode the value part and create key value pairs i.e. variable1=Some%20value&variable2=Another%20Value

Comment: I think this is where I may be getting the bad request as I don't know what the syntax is for actually passing the list of parameters.  I guessed at - Dim postString As String = String.Format("customeremailaddress={0}&customername={1}&referenceid={2}&languagecode={3}&expirydays={4}", customeremailaddress, customername, referenceid, languagecode, expirydays) - but I'm sure this doesn't look right?

Comment: You need to combine @Sani 's answer with wrapping HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode() around your values i.e. Dim customeremailaddress As String = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("r.test@test.com")

Comment: You are now writing the bytes TWICE. This is why the content length doesn't match. You do not need the `StreamWriter`. Remove all code in regards of the `requestWriter` object. As bUKaneer says, you also need to `UrlEncode` the values in the query string.

Comment: I have put up the current version of the code (still returning 400 error) with changes mentioned although instead of encoding each of the strings I have encoded the "postString" concatenated string, is this ok?  Also, HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode was giving an error (reference to a non shared member...), I assume HttpUtility.UrlEncode is what I actually need? @Sani

Comment: On the client side use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx). You should NOT UrlEncode both the whole string but rather the values separately. `Dim customeremailaddress As String = ("r.test@bsava.com")` should be `Dim customeremailaddress As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("r.test@bsava.com")`. None of the other values will get you in trouble but you should always UrlEncode all values just in case.

Comment: You should always UrlEncode each key and each value separately: `String.Format("{0}={1}&{2}={3}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("customeremailaddress"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("r.test@bsava.com"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("customername"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Ryan"))`

Comment: When you UrlEncode the whole query string you get: `customeremailaddress%3dr.test%40test.com%26customername%3dRyan%26referenceid%3dordertest123%26languagecode%3d1043%26expirydays%3d30` which is not a valid query string. The correct query string you should produce is `customeremailaddress=r.test%40test.com&customername=Ryan&referenceid=ordertest123&languagecode=1043&expirydays=30`

Comment: Ok that makes sense and I have updated the code again.  Still getting a 400 error.  Is there an easy way to test the outgoing request?  I have tested this with a php version and it works fine, so I'm still assuming the parameter list isn't being sent properly. @Sani

Comment: As @bUKaneer pointed out use Fiddler2. Compare the traffic with the traffic of the PHP version and see what differs.

Comment: Wow Fiddler is an awesome tool.  It has shown me that the parameters are being sent ok but still getting a 400 error along with a 401.  It seems in my catch the 401 is being picked up and then the 400 is over writing it.  Still odd that if i change the credentials I just get a 401.  Anyway, is webRequest__1.Credentials = siteCredentials the correct way of passing log in details?  It seems I am (with your help) am very close to cracking this. @Sani

Comment: Yes. That should be the correct way to pass the credentials. Compare the PHP version with VB version in Fiddler to see what is different. That's the only advice I can currently give .

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the bytes of the `postString` not the string itself:

```
Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString)
...
webRequest__1.ContentLength = postBytes.Length
...
Dim requestStream As Stream = webRequest__1.GetRequestStream()
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-27).

Comment: I have made those changes but now get (400) Bad Request on the line - Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(webRequest__1.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) - near the end.

Comment: I have tidied the code a little and am now getting: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.  Something to do with the UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Check that when you are setting the `ContentLength` you are specifying `postBytes.Length` and not `postString.Length`. Also check that when you `Write` to the stream you are specifying the `postBytes.Length` property.

Comment: Have edited the original post with the complete code for the Content-length bytes issue.